# Why am I getting this error message? Python

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I am new to Programming. Just learning about Python ..currently learning about List, Loops & Append

```
groceries = ["apple", "watermelon", "cucumber", "banana"]
print(groceries)
movies = ["Batman", "Superman", "Three Musketeers", "Interstellar"]
print(movies)
movies.APPEND("spiderman")....line 115
print(movies)
```

I get error message "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'APPEND' on line 115" when I try the append method

Comment: Write it in lowercase.

Comment: `.append` not `.APPEND`

Comment: its append(). python case sensitive. Better you use any IDEs so that most of these kind of errors can be caught.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacks / list in python - how does it append?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244003/stacks-list-in-python-how-does-it-append)

Answer (score 4):

Change "APPEND" to "append".

Answer (score 1):

Python methods are case-sensitive. When you want to append something to your list, it should always say "append".